# Discord bot cooldown doesn´t work in the drop down menu

Tags: discord.py, bots

I am here to ask you for some help with my discord bot.
Everything work just a fine, but I wanted my bot to be more like gui thing instead of writing every command to chat. So I made everything to dropdown menu. Everything works, but cooldowns not.

```
@client.command()    
@commands.cooldown(1,3600,commands.BucketType.user)    
async def reuploadprace(ctx):    
    await open_account(ctx.author)    
    user = ctx.author    
    users = await get_bank_data()    
    await ctx.send(f"Přišel ti příjem z reklam od PH. Celkem {reuploadlove} € .")    
    users[str(user.id)]["moneybag"] += int(reuploadlove)     
    with open("banka.json", "w") as f:     
        json.dump(users, f) 


@client.command()
async def vyberprace(ctx):
await ctx.send("Co dnes chceš dělat ??",
                   components=[
                     Select(placeholder="Vyber práci",
                          options=[
                            SelectOption(label="Sockovat",
                                         value="socka",
                                         description="Vysockuješ nějaký love na autobusáku. Sockovat můžeš jednou za 30 vteřin."),
                            SelectOption(label="Oprava stroje v Hamečku ",
                                         value="oprava",
                                         description="Jedeš ve 3 ráno opravit stroj do Hamečka. Opravovat můžeš jednou za 30 minut."),
                            SelectOption(label="Stahovat premium videa a uploudovat to na PH ",
                                         value="reupload",
                                         description="dalčí popis není nutný. Stahovat můžeš jednou za 1 hodinu.")],
                                    custom_id="pracevyber")])
    
interaction = await client.wait_for("select_option", check=lambda inter: inter.custom_id == "pracevyber")
pracevyber = interaction.values[0] 

if pracevyber == "socka":
    await ctx.invoke(sockovat)

if pracevyber == "reupload":
    await ctx.invoke(reuploadprace)
```

With this code When I trigger it by using chat everything works, money added to balance and Cooldown works too. But when I trigger it from dropdown menu it add´s money, and everything, but cooldown wont start. Any experience with this ? Thanks for reading guys.. and I hope someon can help me with this trouble.
Have a nice rest of the day !

Comment: Where is the code with the dropdown menu?

Comment: @Chuaat Sorry, I added whole code now.

Comment: Are you sure you are using `discord.py`? (`on_select_option` isn't a valid event and `discord.Interaction` doesn't have a `values` property

Comment: @Mr.Brawler Yes I am using  discord.py,  discord_components and discord.ext command and json. Problem is that cooldown works only if you use it from chat like if you type  m!reuploadprace into discord chat it works, but if you select option in dropdown menu command run but cooldown not .

Comment: This doesn't seem to be `discord.py`, since `on_select_option` isn't a valid event.

Comment: @Mr.Brawler They are using `discord_components` alongside `discord.py`

Comment: Oh, I am not familiar with `discord_components`. By the way, `discord.py` development has resumed. They have added all the latest features including buttons, selects and slash commands.